# Style on ContextMenu and MenuItem in a TableView

Tags: css, javafx-8

I want to apply some style on my ContextMenu and MenuItem in a TableView. It works simply : Right Click on the Row and you have the ContextMenu for this row. However the ContextMenu and MenuItem are built like that :

```
final ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem removeitem = new MenuItem("Remove");
```

I tried to apply a CSS like that :

```
.table-view .context-menu .menu-item
```

and many others but with no results.
However It works when I add the style in my code with setStyle but I want to know if we can do it in CSS (I guess yes ...).

Comment: Have you checked the [CSSReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#contextmenu) ?

Comment: Yeah : /
I tried something like .table-view > .context-menu with no results.
It still use the main .context-menu I have in my CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is the label inside the MenuItem you are trying to style use

```
.table-view .context-menu .menu-item .label
{
   -fx-text-fill: red;
}
```

The MenuItem itself has no (meaningful?) stylable item s itself, at least the documentation does not list any.

Comment: It works like this.
I thought by modifying .table-view .context-menu was enough to apply it on the substructure.
Wrong ...